# Riemann integral vs Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be analytic on a domain $\Omega$ of the complex plane, such that the closed disc $\overline{D(0,R)}$ is contained in $\Omega$. What is the difference between
$$ \int_{D(0,R)}|f(w)|dm(w)$$
and
$$\iint_{D(0,R)}|f(x,y)|dxdy$$
where $dm$ is the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb R^2=\mathbb C$?

Comment: None. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Zip, zilch, nada, nothing.

Comment: understood, thank u all, i'm going to candidate my question to be the most useless in the planet for this year!! :)

Comment: @bateman: No. It is not useless at all. The Riemann integral and Lebesgue integral are defined very differently, so one needs to prove that they give the same answer when applied to a continuous function. Of course, once you have seen the proof, you can take the result for granted.